# Is it possbile to use Java SE version above 8 in Eclipse or any other IDE?

Tags: java, eclipse

I want to use the new JDK 11 (Version 11.0.2) in my Projects and i installed it right away. I also set my path variable to the JDK and deleted the old JAVA_HOME variable. But when i want to set the new build path in exlipse it is saying Java SE 11 (and also 9 and 10) are unbound. Im just able to use Java SE 8 and below.

I tried to set my path variable and my JAVA_HOME variable correctly to C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-11.0.2 and C:\Program Files\Java\jdk.11.0.2\bin but that did not work for me.
Also i figured out that my JDK is set to java version 11.0.2 by using the command prompt

```
javac -version
--> javac 11.0.2
```

Java version is still 1.8.0_202

```
java -version
--> java version "1.8.0_202"
--> Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_202-b08)
--> Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.202-b08, mixed mode)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tell Eclipse about the JDK/JREs you want it to use in the Preferences in 'Java > Installed JREs'.

Connect the execution environments to a JDK/JRE in the Preferences in 'Java > Installed JREs > Execution Environments'.

Set the compiler compliance levels you want in the Preferences in 'Java > Compiler'.

For individual projects specify the JDK/JRE to use in the project Properties in the 'Java Build Path' page (Libraries tab).

You can also set compiler compliance levels for a Project in the 'Java Compiler' properties.

Use the 'Run > Run Configurations' to set the JDK/JRE used when running your program from within Eclipse.

For full Java 11 support you need to be running the current Eclipse (2019-03) or Eclipse 2018-12, earlier versions don't support it.

Comment: I use 2018-12, so that shouldn't be a problem. I solved my issue with just adding the JDK path to the Installed JREs. Thank you!

Comment: @HerbertGrönemeyer Have you added Java 11 JDK in _Window > Preferences: Java > Installed JREs_? Otherwise, you can use it in your project.

Comment: I added it in my preferences, not directly over the context menu. But know i can choose it in my Project`s build-path.