# Error: Could not find or load main class sun.applet.AppletViewer. Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: sun.applet.AppletViewer

Tags: java, eclipse

I'm trying to write some simple codes from the book **The Art and Science of Java**. As an example, I am writing the codes of `Liftoff` but I get the same error every time I write `extends ConsoleProgram`.

```
import acm.program.*;

public class Countdown extends ConsoleProgram {

    public void run() {
        for (int t = START; t >= 0; t--) {
            println(t);
        }

        println("Liftoff!");
    }

    private static final int START = 10;
}
```

I expect the output:

```
10
9
8
7
6
5
4
3
2
1
Liftoff
```

Comment: Looks like ConsoleProgram is using the old AppletViewer which is no longer present in Java 11 and later. You would need to go back to an older Java to run this (probably Java 8) - or use a more up to date book.

Comment: I am using Version 8 update 211, still have the same error. Should i downgrade to the version just 'Java 8'. What is the way of doing this? Thanks @greg-449.

Comment: The update level doesn't matter. If running this from Eclipse look at the 'Run > Run Configuration' entry for your program to see which Java is being used.

Comment: Run>Run Conf>Java Applet  it seems 'JavaSE -10' and Run>Run Conf>Java Aplication>ConsoleProgram 'Java SE 11.0.1' as Workspace default JRE. So how can i change to 'Java 8' ? @greg-449

Comment: @ErolErtas Add the Java 8 JDK in _Window > Preferences: Java > Installed JREs_ and make sure the compiler compliance level is set to 1.8 in _Project > Properties: Java Compiler_.

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55666296/2670892) covers the various places Java is configured in Eclipse.

Comment: Thanks a lot, it works now